# d3.js Text element within path element issue

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to put a text inside a path boundary. But the text element keeps getting embedded within the path element in the svg and does not render.

see:
http://bl.ocks.org/arun4444/67840328019f268cc856

any suggestions?

thanks much !!

Comment: Don't append to the `path`, append to the `g`. http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/2201b447ac8c27104986

Comment: thx, worked like a charm.